# How to keep an eye on identity theft while away and out of the country?

Tags: united-states, credit, travel, identity-theft, working-abroad

Greetings,

I have been relocated by my company to the US and lived there for a few years.
Now I'm back home.
Being away I'm suspecting that I'm more susceptible to identity thefts.

I'm looking for a few good steps to take considering I'm not very active financially.
One thing I did and been happy about us [opt out of credit card offers for 5 years](http://www.optoutprescreen.com/).

What other precautions would you recommend I take?

- would it make sense to sign up for the banks identity protections programs?
- how about freezing/locking credit?
- I've heard that there are banks that will allow one to mandate asking for a PIN *on top* of the social security number when using phone banking, anybody willing to share experience with that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any experience with bank identity protection, but i think those are just an insurance. If something happens they help you to restore the history, but they don't actively prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put a freeze on your credit
2. Check your credit report from one bureau once every 4 months via annualcreditreport.com.  The service is free and you can get only one report from a bureau each year, hence the spacing out
3. Check your credit  regularly from another free service CreditKarma.com
4. A way to [get your credit scores for free from all three bureaus without paying extra](http://www.moneycone.com/howto-get-your-credit-score-from-all-3-credit-bureaus-for-free/)

All these are online services and can be checked from outside the country.  (Don't check them from a public computer though!)

Comment: The annualcreditreport.com is the actual official free credit report. Don't use the services that give you a score.